# Chromium browser does not launch on Ubuntu 16

Tags: chromium

When I launch the application it does not open. When I try it from command prompt following error message is displayed

```
$ chromium-browser --disable -extensions
[4168:4201:1016/185019.088022:FATAL:nss_util.cc(632)] NSS_VersionCheck("3.26") failed. NSS >= 3.26 is required. Please upgrade to the latest NSS, and if you still get this error, contact your distribution maintainer.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 0):

Open Software Updater in your applications.  In the setting, ensure that "Important Security Updates" is checked. Then close the window.

Open a terminal, run;

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install libnss3
```

This should update/install NSS and you should now be able to open Chromium.